# How to set rtlinux thread priority in Linux

Tags: kernel

How to set the priority of real time threads in rtlinux. Which is highest priority and which is lowest?

Comment: You can use [`schedtool(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/schedtool.8.html) to set (real-time) scheduling policies and priorities of processes, which are described in [`sched_setscheduler(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) and the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/). You may get better answers for this on [Unix.SE]

Comment: Possible duplicate on [Unix.SE]: [Real time processes scheduling in Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/154867/47852)